# Hyperlink text in a form to send-MailMessage in Powershell

Tags: forms, email, powershell, variables, sendmail

Im a new to sending email in powershell and Im trying to create a form that hyperlinks text to be able to click and send-mailMessage to... My variable now is:

```
$ServiceDeskEmail = Send-MailMessage -TO "SERVICEDESK@DOMAIN.COM <SERVICEDESK@DOMAIN.COM>"
```

Something i was much better at in HTML... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution I came up with:

```
$Email_Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
$Email_Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(60, 38)
$Email_Label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20) 
$Email_Label.LinkColor = "DarkRed"
$Email_Label.Text = "user@domain.com" 
$Email_Label.add_Click({[System.Diagnostics.Process]::start("mailto:user@domain.com")})
$Email_Label.BackColor = "Transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the message's body as HTML encoded string before sending it. While you are at it, set rest of the parameters as variables too. Like so,

```
$body = 'The results <a href="http://example.com/foo">are ready</a>'
$smtp = 'mail.example.com'
$to = 'reciever@example.com'
$from  = 'sender@example.com'
$subject = 'HTML report sample'
send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
```

Take a look [at the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) too for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("lahcen.ziyate@gmail.com", email);
mm.Subject = "subject";
mm.Body = "<h1>welcome to digital world</h1></br></br>";
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
nc.UserName = "lahcen.ziyate@gmail.com";
nc.Password = "";
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = nc;
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Send(mm);
```